# In React, Is it good practice to search for certain element in DOM?

Tags: reactjs, dom, classname

Is it good to just specify className for element so i could find it later in the DOM through getElementsByClassName for manipulations?

Answer (score 2):

Adding a class to find the DOM element? Sure you can do that, but [**refs**](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) are probably the better solution.

Manipulating the DOM element? That's an absolute no-go. The part of the DOM that is managed by React should not be manipulated my anything else but React itself.

Comment: Any element created through React should not be manipulated manually. Anything else is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you come from jQuery background, or something similar, you will have the tendency to manipulate element directly as such:

```
<div class="notification">You have an error</div>

.notification {
   display: none;
   color: red;
}

.show {
   display: block;
}

handleButtonClick(e) {
   $('.notification').addClass('show');
}
```

In React, you achieve this by declaring what your elements (components) should do in different states of the app.

```
const Notification = ({ error }) => {
   return error
      ? <div className="notification">You have an error</div>
      : null;
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
   state = { error: false };

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <Notification error={this.state.error} />
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ error: true })}>
               Click Me
            </button>
   }
}
```

The code above isn't tested, but should give you the general idea.

By default, the state of `error` in `Parent` is `false`. In that state, `Notification` will not render anything. If the button is clicked, `error` will be `true`. In that state, `Notification` will render the `div`.

Try to think declaratively instead of imperatively.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

When using React, you should think about how you can use state to control how components render. `this.setState` performs a rerender, which means you can control how elements are rendered by changing `this.state`. Here's a small example. I use `this.state.show` as a boolean to change the opacity of the HTML element.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    show: true
  }
}

handleClick() {
  this.setState({show: false})
}

render() {
  const visibility = this.state.show ? 1 : 0
  return (
    <button style={{opacity: visibility} onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
       Click to make this button invisible
    </button>
  )
}
```

Comment: Yes, but does react come in handy if i want, for example, hide menu(contains with react components) by clicking on another React component, or manage React components on window resize?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by window resize, but for the first one, yes. You can use the same logic for removing and adding DOM elements, for example: `{this.state.show ? <Component/> :  null }`. The `<Component/>` won't get mounted until `this.state.show` is changed to true, just like with my opacity example.